# Общее правило для классов

Tags: html, css

Последнее время часто использую такую практику: если на странице много плавающих элементов, то всем им я присваиваю класс, например, left, и этому классу задаю правило:

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
```

Тоже самое относится и к другим правилам, которые часто используются на странице. В итоге выходит, что я сокращаю css-файл, но нагромождаю классами разметку. И вот сейчас задумался - а правильный ли это подход? Что лучше и гибче по вашему мнению и как грамотней?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вспомогательные классы нужно использовать без фанатизма. Разделять каждое свойство на вспомогательные классы не нужно.

```
.css-selector {
  color: #00f;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
```

Вы же не станете вместо этого делать так:

```
.color-blue {
  color: #00f;
}

.border-bottom-dotted {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.left {
  float: left;
}
```

И создавать дом элемент `<a href="#" class="color-blue border-bottom-dotted cursor-pointer left">Элемент</a>`.

Вспомогательные классы хороши когда нужно избежать запись стилей непосредственно в тег элемента или когда один или несколько элементов могут отличаться от других c таким же набором свойств, к примеру, только выравниванием текста. В таком случае удобнее запись:

```
.css-selector {
  font: 1rem/1.5 helvetica, arial, sans;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
}
```

а необходимым элементам добавляется хелпер класс *.align-right*, а каким то `.align-justify` вместо такой конструкции:

```
.css-selector,
.css-selector-alignright,
.css-selector-.alignjustify  {
  font: 1rem/1.5 helvetica, arial, sans;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
}

.css-selector-alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

.css-selector-.alignjustify {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нормальный это подход :)

Посмотрите на bootstrap, zurb foundation, ui kit, semantic ui — везде этот подход практикуется. И все эти решения пользуются популярностью. Вероятно, следующим для вас шагом будет ознакомиться с одним из этих фреймворков, проникнуться идеей, и сократить затраты времени на разработку.

Comment: Я задался этим вопросом после того, как нужно было в меню 5-ю элементам списка присвоить class="left", что показалось мне излишеством.

Comment: в данном конкретном случае — да, неверное решение. В этом случае более правильно было бы вспомнить, почему таблицы стилей называются каскадными, и сделать что-нибудь в духе .navbar li { float: left; }

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю, что это зависит от проекта. Но если вы используете определенное правило очень часто, то лучше вынести его в отдельный класс и использовать этот класс в html